# Static or dynamic linking of .SWF files

Tags: flash, dynamic-linking, static-linking

If you compile a Flash project into a .swf file and that project refers to another .swf file, is it linked statically or dynamically?  That is, is the second .swf file contained physically in the first .swf file or does the first .swf file refer to the second at run-time?

Answer (score 0):

It can be [either](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=performance_07.html) depending on your project [settings](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=performance_07.html).